# Disable Invalid object name check from script

Tags: sql, sql-server

Before our dacpac project publish we run a folder with scripts from our CI. THis does not work when we deploy to a empty database for testing

Even if I check if the table exists it breaks because sql pre checks checks the query

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.MyTable', N'U') IS NOT NULL AND
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable where Something = 'foo')
```

Can I somehow disable that check from my script?

Comment: Flip the logic round `IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.MyTable', N'U') IS NULL CREATE TABLE ...`

Comment: Presumably the dacpac publish is responsible for actually creating the table? What is this script doing? You can probably break this up into two nested IFs anyway. If the table doesn't exist yet the statement will be subject to deferred compilation and only raise an error if actually executed

Comment: @GordonLinoff - It makes sense in that they only want to run the select from table part if the table exists. But SQL Server won't do short circuiting like this. The whole boolean expression (`expr1 AND expr2`) needs to be able to be fully compiled before executing which won't be possible when the table doesn't exist - as `expr2` references a non existent object

Comment: The short answer is no - you cannot disable that. Without knowing the actual goal, useful suggestions are difficult. Dynamic sql can get you around the issue. Clever division of your scripts into batches might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use sp_executesql;

```
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.MyTable', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @ret int;
        DECLARE @s nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT @ret = (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable where Something = ''foo'')';  
        EXEC sp_executesql @s, N'@ret int OUTPUT', @ret OUTPUT;

        IF @ret = 1 
        BEGIN
            -- do something if the table exists and the select returns a record
            select getdate();  
        END
    END
END
```